# Extract filename with and without terminating characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string that will contain one of the following text:

1. inline; filename="name.extension";
2. inline; filename="name.extension"
3. inline; filename='name.extension';
4. inline; filename='name.extension'
5. inline; filename=name.extension;
6. inline; filename=name.extension

I want to extract ***name.extension*** and can handle the first 5 cases but I can't figure out how to do all cases with a single regex. Everything I tried becomes too greedy. Is that even possible?

The regex that works for the first 5 is:

```
/filename=["']?(.*)(?=["']?;)/
```

The name.extension is in the first capture group and must allow any valid character for a file name in linux. That includes ' and " and ; in it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: None of the answers so far identify unbalanced quotes, such as a single quote before and no quote after. Do you want the method to confirm that a quote, if present, is balanced?

Comment: Actually, that would be the cherry on the cake :-)

Comment: At a certain point you need a grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in three stages.

1. Split on `;` to separate out the statements.
2. Split the key/value pair on `=`.
3. Deal with the quoting of the value.

Here's a basic example.

```
def get_value(line)
    # Split into statements
    statements = line.split(/\s*;\s*/)

    # Extract the value of the 2nd statement
    _,value = statements[1].split(/\s*=\s*/)

    # Strip the quotes
    value.gsub!(/^(['"]?)(.*)\1$/, '\2')

    return value
end
```

There's a few edge cases that doesn't handle: What if the statement you're interested in isn't the second one? But that can be fixed up as needed. It's a lot easier to improve your parsing when it's done in multiple steps rather than trying to cram it into one regex.

For example, this correctly handles embedded and escaped quotes like `%q[inline; filename="name's.extension"]` and `%q[inline; filename="name's.\\"extension\\""]`.

---

If you really want to do it as a single regex, ok, you asked for it.

```
re = /
    \bfilename
    \s*=\s* 
    (?:
        (?<quote>['"])(?<value>.*)\k<quote> |
        (?<value>[^;]+)
    )
/x
return re.match(line)['value']
```

That splits the handling of the extension into two alternatives: one with quotes and one without. Otherwise `filename=name.ext;` will pick up the semicolon and I can't figure out another way to stop it that doesn't introduce a new problem.

For example, `/\bfilename\s*=\s*(?<quote>['"]?)(?<value>.*?)\k<quote>;?$/` will work on the test data, but then it will fail if there's anything after the semicolon like `%q[inline; filename='name.extension'; foo]`.

You asked for expert regex knowledge. Part of being a regex expert is to know when you shouldn't use a regex. This should probably be handled with a grammar or you'll be constantly chasing edge cases.

Comment: Yes, I could have solved it using code but I was really curious to see if someone with expert regex knowledge could solve this. If the answer is that a regex can't cover all the cases, then I will fall back to programming. I'm trying to patch something in paperclip and the simplest thing would have been to simply fix the regex.

Comment: @Whyves I edited in doing it with a single regex, but as you can see it's kinda nasty. If you mean this [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) I don't understand why you can't replace the regex with a function call. Maybe you should ask a question about what you're trying to patch.

Comment: Ok, you made your point loud and clear :-) I do believe in readability and maintainability too. However, I must say WOW for the regex. As for paperclip, that's not a problem I'll use a function. It's just that its current handling of the "content-disposition' header is faulty as I encountered an edge case. It's currently handled with a regex so the easiest way would have been to fix that single line of code. Thanks a lot for the time and energy that went into this answer!

Comment: @Whyves You're welcome! And yes, HTTP headers should definitely be parsed, not regexed (is that a verb now?) You'll want to have a look at [the grammar](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266#section-4.1) and also [the examples in RFC 6266](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266#section-5). I wish I could recommend a good Ruby grammar class. You can do it with a series of regexes that reproduce the grammar, [here's an example](https://github.com/jshttp/content-disposition/blob/master/index.js) though I don't know how good it is.

Comment: Your regex points out an advantage of named capture groups, something I had not considered previously: two groups can be given the same name.

Comment: @Schwern Thanks for the references. That's exactly the problem I have encountered: a grammar problem. The filename value isn't enclosed in quotes while Paperclip explicitly expect them.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/filename=["']?([^"';]+)/
```

It should return the string in the first capture group.

```
[
  'inline; filename="name.extension";',
  'inline; filename="name.extension"',
  "inline; filename='name.extension'",
  "inline; filename='name.extension';",
  "inline; filename=name.extension;",
  "inline; filename=name.extension"
].map { |str| str[/filename=["']?([^"';]+)/, 1] == "name.extension" }

 => [true, true, true, true, true, true]
```

Comment: That works on the set given, but fails on interior quotes like `%q[inline; filename="name's.extension"]`

Comment: That's why it makes it difficult (at least for me). I don't control the file name and thus it can contains single or double quotes as well as semicolon. This is why I used a positive lookahead but it doesn't handle one of the case.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple and maintainable, don't use a regex:

```
arr = %q(inline; filename="name.extension";
inline; filename="name.extension"
inline; filename='name.extension';
inline; filename='name.extension'
inline; filename=name.extension;
inline; filename=name.extension).lines.map(&:chomp)

p arr.map{|str|  str.delete(%q("';) ).split("=").last}
```

This makes use of ruby's flexible string literal syntax; the %q() trick is used 2 times here, providing hassle-free handling of single and double quotation marks.

Comment: This will strip out any embedded quotes like `inline; filename="name's.extension";` or `inline; filename="name.\"extension\"";`

Comment: @Schwern yes, but AFAIK those are dubious in filenames anyway.

Comment: That violates the [Robustness Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle). Since the quotes are deleted it could even be a security issue leaving an opening to trick a process into reading a different file.

Comment: @steenslag might be dubious but I don't control the file name and beside they are legit characters.